# How can I simulate mouse movement in DirectX and similar games?

Tags: python, c++, winapi, automation, pyautogui

I have recently been searching around for a way to automate games where **mouse movement is crucial**, however I have not yet been able to find any way to simulate hardware mouse input in C/C++
I have come across many articles and s.o. questions where python is used, suggesting using *PyAutoGUI* and *PyDirectInput*, and similar python libraries which I have tried, but I am looking for something with finer control.

As far as I know there is no way to simulate mouse **motion** the same way you can simulate key presses or mouse clicks. Everything I have tried so far is only blipping the cursor to certain X/Y coordinates. In first person games the mouse is always reset to the center when the mouse is moved as to be able to control the camera effectively, which does not react to teleporting the cursor.
I have been unable to find anything regarding this topic anywhere, though it should be possible (and fairly simple)

If I could get an explanation for the way FP games deal with mouse movement, how to simulate real life mouse movement, search terms or even similar problems, this would be greatly appreciated!

- I have tried multiple python libraries (including PyAutoGUI and PyDirectInput)
- Windows API (C++)
- Moving the mouse 1 pixel and back (Python)

If you wish to reproduce this phenomenon you can:

1. Open (almost) any game (Ex. HL2, GTA 5, Roblox, Valorant, Counter Strike)
2. Go into first person
3. Try to move the mouse programmatically (Ex. Python script, C w/ Win32 API)

And you will see that your camera most likely doesn't move much, if at all.

I am more or less having the same problem as [this fella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921040/windows-c-how-to-simulate-mouse-movement-in-fps-games), but with multiple games

Comment: You will, most likely, need to emulate a hardware device, i.e., implement a mouse driver. USB device emulation might work as well (see [Write a UDE client driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/writing-a-ude-client-driver)).

Comment: You might need to increase the speed of the mouse movement, and some games require you to click and drag, so you might want to try that (if you haven't already). I also agree with @IInspectable, just one python library is probably not going to be enough.